# How to read all text files in Github repository?

Tags: python, github, repository

I want to read all text files in Github repository, but text files addresses are different with raw text address.
[Trump Speeches](https://github.com/PedramNavid/trump_speeches/tree/master/data)

For example look at this link:
[speech_00.txt in first status](https://github.com/PedramNavid/trump_speeches/blob/master/data/speech_00.txt)

Now, speech_00.txt has different address with in raw mode
[speech_00.txt in raw status](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PedramNavid/trump_speeches/master/data/speech_00.txt)

How could I handle that without editing addresses(for example adding 
githubusercontent or removing blob)

Also, I read a sample text file using this code:

```
import urllib
response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PedramNavid/trump_speeches/master/data/speech_72.txt")
Text = response.read()
Text=Text.decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use your code(@N.Yasarturk), and I edited it to get all files. But I asked, Are there other methods(without editing addresses) for reading these files from Github repository?

```
import urllib
# Get master directory
speech_dir ="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PedramNavid/trump_speeches/master/data/"
# Iterate through all speeches in directory, from 00 to 73
cur_speech = 0
temp=str(cur_speech)
end_speech = 73
while (cur_speech <= end_speech):
    # Change the speech you want to get
    if(cur_speech<10):
        temp="0"+str(cur_speech)
    else:
        temp=str(cur_speech)
    speech_nm = (speech_dir+'speech_' + temp +'.txt')
    print(speech_nm)
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(speech_nm)
    # Do what you need to with the speech
    Text = response.read()
    Text = Text.decode("utf-8")
    print(Text)
    # Update to the new speech
    cur_speech +=1
```

Answer (score 1):

A sorta hacky way to implement this (based on the way that that directory in particular is
structured) would be to make a loop iteratively add to the string that you are inputting
as your filepath:

```
import urllib

# Get master directory
speech_dir ="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PedramNavid/trump_speeches/master/data/"
# Iterate through all speeches in directory, from 00 to 73
cur_speech = 00
end_speech = 73
while (cur_speech <= end_speech):
    # Change the speech you want to get
    speech_nm = ('speech_' + str(cur_speech) +'.txt')
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(speech_nm)
    # Do what you need to with the speech
    Text = response.read()
    Text = Text.decode("utf-8")
    # Update to the new speech
    cur_speech +=1
```

This way, you'll go through each speech in that particular directory.

Comment: I test your solution in Colab but it has some errors. If I want to use this method, I could write it by handling string for name of the each file and without any error. But youre used string modification method.